# Posting a form with ajax and unknown form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Using jQuery its quite simple to post data to a server using ajax.

**Is there a jquery function to post a form using the form name and receive the status from the server like other traditional ajax post calls.**

But what if we simply wanted to post a form by its name or ID and when I have an unknown set of form fields.

What Id like to do is fetch the form on the page, and just submit the form and current data

See example code:

HTML

```
<form name='myform'>
    <input type='hidden' value='1' name='somefield'>
    <input type='hidden' value='2' name='somefield2'>
    <input type='hidden' value='3' name='somefield3'>

</form>

<a href='#' class='postform' form_name='myform'>post using ajax</a>
```

JS

```
$('.postform').click( function() {

    form_name = $(this).attr('form_name');

    postto = 'http://mysite-endpoint.com/api';

    form = $(form_name).submit(postto).done(function(data)
    {
        var ndata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if(ndata.status=='error')
        {
            //display error
        }

        if(ndata.status=='success')
        {
            //looks good
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is there a jquery function to do this ?

Comment: To do what? It's not clear form your post.

Comment: `$('form[name="form_name"]').submit()` But it's better to use id - `$('#form_id').submit()`.

Comment: @u_mulder +1, here's more http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: The OP already uses `.submit()` so it's very unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Juhana  He wants a selector with `form_name`

Comment: exactly, can the form be posted just using the name.

Comment: @IEnumerable what's wrong with the comment u_mulder posted?

Comment: Yes but will the .done() contract handler work with that too?

Comment: @IEnumerable No it won't because submit() doesn't returns a promise. BUT have you any `submit` handler bound to the FORM (using jQuery btw)? I ask it because the default behaviour of submiting the FORM will redirect the page, so your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: @IEnumerable I think you need to use AJAX for the behavior you want.

Comment: Yes, the point is to post using an ajax post. And receive a response.

No redirection is required. How to do this when you dont know the field forms

Comment: @IEnumerable So use the search function, there is already many many examples regarding submiting a FROM using ajax

Comment: @Nathan Taylors answer is nice, but you could just as well use an onclick event instead of a submit event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery $.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to tokenize the form and submit based on the form attributes. Something like this:

```
$('#someform').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        type: $form.attr('method') || 'get',
        data: $form.serialize(),
    }).then(function() {
        alert('success');
    }, function() {
        alert('error');
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jztborhq/)

Comment: YES! this looks like what Im after. Ajax to send, and receive the response.
So jQ has serialize().  hmmm

Comment: Is a submit event even necessary here? An onclick event on the link could do the same.

Comment: @Mouser that's better to use the submit event of the FORM for better cross browser support, especially if user press `return` key on input inside the FORM or use the attribute `form` on a button outside of the FORM BUT that's really depends what OP is looking for regarding this kind of behaviour. EDIT: i see, the FORM contains only hidden inputs, so ya, no so much an issue here to just use the click event

Comment: thankyou all so much.  I particularly like the `type: $form.attr('method') || 'get',` line to get the default method. Sorry, Im such a noob when it comes to jQ.